# How can I move a d3 map using zoom behavior and transforms?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm using d3v4 to build a map. I'm using a Robinson projection, d3's Zoom behavior for panning and zooming, and css transform to actually position the svg elements themselves. Given a lat,long pair, I'd like to center the map using the current zoom.

I've seen many examples of how to center a map in d3, and how to attach the zoom behavior, but so far each example either

- uses an older version of d3
- doesn't use the zoom behavior (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206489, for example)
- manipulate the projection itself rather than using a css transform (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340)
- don't use a map projection at all (https://bl.ocks.org/catherinekerr/b3227f16cebc8dd8beee461a945fb323)

Given a lat/long pair I can use my projection to get the X/Y on a non-translated, non-zoomed svg. How can I create a transform from that point to center it in the view?

My map setup:

```
const {clientHeight: height, clientWidth: width} = div;
svg.setAttribute("width", `${width}`);
svg.setAttribute("height", `${height}`);

// projection
this.projection = geoRobinson()
    // center and scale to container properly
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale((width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI);

// calculate zoom limits
const actualHeight = width / ratio;
const verticalExtent = (actualHeight - height) / 2;

// setup mouse listeners for panning and zooming on svg.
this.zoomBehavior = zoom<SVGSVGElement, any>()
    // set min and max zoom factor
    .scaleExtent([0.75, 8]) // based on playing around with numbers until it looked pleasing

    // transform map on zoom and pan
    .on("zoom", () => {
        const currentTransform = this.state.transform;
        const newTransform: ZoomTransform = d3event.transform;

        if (
            !currentTransform ||
            hasChanged(currentTransform.x, newTransform.x) ||
            hasChanged(currentTransform.y, newTransform.y) ||
            hasChanged(currentTransform.k, newTransform.k)
        ) {
            this.setState({ // updates the css transform of the SVG map
                transform: newTransform,
            });
        }
    });

// apply zoom behavior to whole svg
const svgSelection = select(svg);

svgSelection.call(this.zoomBehavior)
```

I've looked at `zoomBehavior.translateTo()` and other functions but I don't know how to convert to whatever units they are using.

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering and googling I found this example: https://bl.ocks.org/andybarefoot/765c937c8599ef540e1e0b394ca89dc5

It has d3v4, a zoom behavior, and the ability to recenter the map on command.

---

What I do is this:

1. Get the pixel position of the origin, as if the map were unzoomed (or zoom = 1)
2. use a formula to get the css transform if that origin were moved to the center of the view, and zoomed. For x: `(width / 2) - (longitude * zoom)`
3. use `svg.call(behavior, newTransform)` to apply the transform (and apparently update the behavior, too. Or it doesn't need to be updated.)

My code:

```
const coords = this.projection([longitude, latitude]);
if (!coords) {
    return;
}

let actualScale: number = 1;
if (scale !== undefined) {
    actualScale = Math.min(MAX_ZOOM, Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, 1, scale));
}

 // get pixel size of svg
const {clientHeight: height, clientWidth: width} = svg;

// build new transform
const transform = zoomIdentity
    .translate(width / 2 - coords[0] * actualScale, height / 2 - coords[1] * actualScale)
    .scale(actualScale);

// apply and save transform
select(svg)
    .transition() // omit this and the next line if you don't want transitions
    .duration(200)
    .call(this.zoomBehavior.transform, transform);
```